# Powershell - Windows backup, get number of available copies

Tags: powershell, windows-server

how to get number of available backup copies of Windows backup in powershell please?

Get-WBSummary returns count of all copies but i need only actual target.

I tryed (wbadmin get versions).count but it count all lines. It looks like that:
[wbadmin get versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WySN.png)

Thank you.

Michal

Answer (score 0):

```
(wbadmin get versions | Select-String -Pattern "Backup Time" | Measure-Object).Count
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?